# Oracle unpivot grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I am trying to unpivot columns to rows so that they are grouped by a unit number that I was hoping to construct in the unpivot function

To simplify the explanation see the example query below:

```
select
'123456789' student
,'01/Jul/2020' unit_1_date
,'Mathematics 'unit_1_subject
,'01/Aug/2020' unit_2_date
,'English 'unit_2_subject
from
dual
```

which outputs five columns:

```
student     unit_1_date   unit_1_subject   unit_2_date    unit_2_subject
123456789   01/Jul/2020   Mathematics      01/Aug/2020    English
```

I wish to unpivot these columns so they can be grouped by a unit number and display like this:

```
student     unit_number     unit_date      unit_subject   
123456789   1               01/Jul/2020    Mathematics      
123456789   2               01/Aug/2020    English
```

I have tried to do this with the unpivot function as shown below:

```
select * from
(select
'123456789' student
,'01/Jul/2020' unit_1_date
,'Mathematics 'unit_1_subject
,'01/Aug/2020' unit_2_date
,'English 'unit_2_subject
from
dual) units
unpivot(unit_date for unit_number in(
unit_1_subject as '1',
unit_1_date    as '1',
unit_2_subject as '2',
unit_2_date    as '2'
))
```

which is outputting the date like this:

```
Student     Unit number    Unit_date 
123456789   1              Mathematics 
123456789   1              01/Jul/2020
123456789   2              English 
123456789   2              01/Aug/2020
```

I'm unsure how to go about grouping two of the columns so they are grouped by a unit number. What's the best way to do this? Is this achievable with the UNPIVOT function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hierarchy query as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      STUDENT,
  3      LEVEL AS UNIT,
  4      CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN UNIT_1_DATE ELSE UNIT_2_DATE END AS UNIT_DATE,
  5      CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN UNIT_1_SUBJECT ELSE UNIT_2_SUBJECT END AS SUBJECT
  6  FROM
  7      ( SELECT
  8              '123456789' STUDENT,
  9              '01/Jul/2020' UNIT_1_DATE,
 10              'Mathematics ' UNIT_1_SUBJECT,
 11              '01/Aug/2020' UNIT_2_DATE,
 12              'English ' UNIT_2_SUBJECT
 13          FROM DUAL
 14      ) CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;

STUDENT         UNIT UNIT_DATE   SUBJECT
--------- ---------- ----------- ------------
123456789          1 01/Jul/2020 Mathematics
123456789          2 01/Aug/2020 English

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `union all`:

```
select 
    student,
    1 unit_number,
    unit_1_date unit_date,
    unit_1_date,
    unit_1_subject
from mytable
union all
select 
    student,
    2 unit_number,
    unit_2_date unit_date,
    unit_2_date,
    unit_2_subject
from mytable
```